# System keeps asking for cryptswap password

Tags: apt, upgrade, suspend, password, encryption

I have a fresh installation of Kubuntu 16.04.1 (kernel 4.13.0-32-generic). The home folder is encrypted (installation option).

The OS keeps asking for the encrypted swap partition password in two cases:

1. On boot, before the log in screen it always asks for the password for cryptswap.
2. On `sudo apt-get upgrade` see image: [image: screenshow of apt-get upgrade]

This causes two major usability problems:

1. One I already asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003921/ubuntu-16-04-shut-down-goes-to-log-screen-always-after-suspend). Still no answer.
2. The other is that the GUI software center does not automatically detect updates, it does only after I do `sudo apt-get update`. Also, it "hangs" when updating from GUI (I suspect that it is waiting for the cryptswap password that from the terminal I can write but not in the GUI).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after lots of search engine fu,  I was able to find someone with the same issue as us. It was a simple fix:

```
sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils --reinstall
sudo update-grub
```

There was a long thread in 2015 about how ecryptfs-utils, GPT partitions, and swap can get a little dicey with systemd.

Comment: the problem in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003921/ubuntu-16-04-shut-down-goes-to-log-screen-always-after-suspend) was also solved, feel free to answer that one too.