# Use swap without password prompt on boot

Tags: 16.04, boot, password, swap

I'm getting a prompt for a password for my swap partition at boot (and a bunch of times when installing updates). I used the fix [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010891/system-keeps-asking-for-cryptswap-password) and it stopped asking me for a password, but the swap partition seemed to be disabled. I re-enabled it by uncommenting the line in /etc/fstab with the UUID of my swap (first line below):

```
UUID=839ce62d-8445-4689-a85a-a7ecc6c6ce5a none swap sw 0 0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

but now it asks for a password again.

All I have to do is hit enter each time, but it's a pain, especially when installing updates, as I have to open the output in the installer and press enter at least three times.

Is there a way to use a swap partition without it asking for a password that I don't use? I kind of need a swap, since I have 4GB RAM and (cheap) integrated graphics (not to mention my SSD should run fast enough for the swap to be at least somewhat useful).

Do I have to make it not encrypt the swap to achieve this, and if so, are there any security reasons not to?

```
Info: Dual-boot Win10/Ubuntu 16.04.3 (and Remix OS)
Swap: /dev/sda5, around 3.32 GiB (fills end of disk)
```

Comment: Do you have a encrypted root partition? if so you could use a swapfile on that. Not sure why its asking for decryption password on updates this seems unnecessary.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Home directory is encrypted, though. Kept me from migrating incorrectly.